# Structural changes in beta of CAPM package

Tags: r, breakpoints, regression, detection

I am trying to detect (in R) structural changes in beta coefficients of CAPM model of selected stock prices. Of course by browsing this web or just googling I came across a lots of R packages dealing with structural changes, e.g. `strucchange` by Zeileis et al. Thats not the problem. The problem is rather trivial.

I have historical prices for Bank of America (Er), benchmark prices of Dow Jones(rmrf) and risk free rates(rf).

In the breakpoints function of `strucchange` package—if I understand it correctly—one should use a regression in the "formula", so should I use `(Er-rf)/(rmrf-rf)~1`. Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 0):

While you do need to put a formula object in the breakpoints function, the formula you are looking for should be about estimating the beta.

Generally, you can estimate the parameters of the CAPM (a and b here) like so:
**NOTE**: this is for a single asset portfolio. The model generalized rather simply.

```
BOA - Rf = a + b(Rm - Rf) + e
```

Where the Rm is your `rmrf`. In R,

```
(Er - rf) ~ (rmrf-rf)
```

R, by default, will include the intercept parameter (the alpha).